# How to report multiple test cases in case of multiple assertions done in single test function?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

How can I report the same number of test cases as assertions with PyTest?

Currently, in my test framework, 1 test function can contain multiple assertions that belong to different test cases in JIRA.

```
# A simple use-case of what I want to achieve

def test_one(request):
    assert  1 == 1 # QA-1234 Passed
    assert  2 == 1 # QA-4567 Failed
```

I have tried to resolve this using `pytest.fixture` but is not scalable solution when the number of assertions gets increased. As shown in the below snippet, I will have to keep creating different pytest test functions for each assertion.

```
value1 = 10
value2 = "golden"
value3 = None

@pytest.fixture()
def check_value1_value2_value3():
    testcase_ids = {}
    testcase_ids['QA-1234'] = value1 == 10
    testcase_ids['QA-5678'] = value2 == 'silver'
    testcase_ids['QA-6789'] = value3 is not None

def test_value1(check_value1_value2_value3):
    testcases = check_value1_value2_value3
    assert testcases['QA-1234'] == True

def test_value2(check_value1_value2_value3):
    testcases = check_value1_value2_value3
    assert testcases['QA-5678'] == True

def test_value3(check_value1_value2_value3):
    testcases = check_value1_value2_value3
    assert testcases['QA-6789'] == False
```

Here are the solutions I have already tried:

1. Creating a marker with multiple JIRA IDs and Updating HTML Report

I have tried lots of things (marking testcase with multiple Jira IDs (works fine in cases of parametrie I am not able to solve this issue. I would be really grateful if anyone could suggest a better way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is a bit unclear to me. Let me be specific to my understanding of the provided problem statement

1. You can try with this pytest-plugin https://pypi.org/project/pytest-jira/0.2.3/ 
   This should solve the purpose you are looking to mark test cases against jira issues
2. a test case could have 'n' number of assertions, but asserting them against a boolean is not a suggested practice - instead return the status of each assertion in a dict form and simplify your assertions

Comment: Can you elaborate on No. #2 with any example?